# What is the proper way to get the count of ticks of a duration in C++1x

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm using C++ to develop my project and I used `std::chrono`.

I need to get a count of ticks of some duration, for example, I may need an integer `3600`, which represents the count of second-ticks of one hour.

To get this integer, I can code as below:

```
int a = 3600; // 1 hour = 3600 sec
int b = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(1h).count();
int c = (1h + 0s).count();
```

Obviously, each of these can give me a `3600`. The first one is quite simple but I'd better add some comment to avoid the magic number `3600`. The second one is quite clear but may I say it's really really too long? And the third one is not long, and `+ 0s` could convert `1h` into `std::chrono::seconds` automatically so I can get what I want, but is it kind of tricky?

So could you please tell me which one is the best in the view of the modern C++ or is there any better code than mine?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. There is no "best" until you define some evaluation criteria. For instance, the second solution is IMO the "best" because it is most readable/understandable, but the third one is "best" since it is shortest.

Comment: `auto sec = std::chrono::seconds(1h).count();`

Comment: @DanielLangr Well, I didn't read the source code of `chrono` but as I knew, it's quite light. So we needn't care about performance. So "best" here is just what you said: readable/understandable, clear.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik OK... I didn't notice that we can initialize a duration with another duration... It seems that your code is the best.

Comment: `std::chrono::duration_cast` is only necessary when moving to a lower precision type, if there is no loss of precision you can just construct directly. E.g. `std::chrono::hours(1s)` doesn't work but `std::chrono::seconds(1h)` does

Comment: You can also make `a`, `b`, `c` and @SergeyKolesnik's answer `constexpr`.  This guarantees that all 4 will generate the exact same object code -- no performance compromises.

Comment: And here's a fifth variation: `constexpr int e = 1h/1s;`

Comment: @HowardHinnant it is not necessary to make those `constexpr` since the compiler will optimize anyway

Comment: It is like the difference between a verbal agreement that the loan will be repaid, and a binding signed contract.  One might happen, might even be likely.  The other is guaranteed, no matter the optimization level.